# Javascript code to hide div

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I would like to make a reservations formula but I have very low knowledge for javascript and ajax.

Here is a sample form: http://info.airprishtina.com/content/index.php?id=20&no_cache=1&L=0

When you **Einfachflug** in the **Online buchen** on the left, the divs that contain the destinations for returning flights disappear. What is the best way to achieve this effect? because I have seen different techniques but I would like to know what is the easiest and the best way!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They change the style.visibility of the objects. That way the hidden objects will still take up space so the form does not change size.

Alternative is to change the style.display between "none" and "" or "block"
Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/VKxFT/

Here is the actual code they use

```
function OneOrTwoWayClick() {
    var cb = getObject('fbengine_ui_flightsearchext_ascx_MultiCity');
    if (cb != null) {
        var rb = getObject('fbengine_ui_flightsearchext_ascx_Ticket2Way');
        if (rb.checked) {
            getObject('fbengine_ui_flightsearchext_ascx_MultiCityPanel').style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
            getObject('fbengine_ui_flightsearchext_ascx_MultiCityPanel').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            cb.checked = false;
            OnClickedMulticity();
        }
    }

    OneOrTwoWayChk();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to use your example, I would like to thank you for your help, have a nice day

Comment: OK so there is another problem because I add and id to 2 input type text fields and then this function only works for the first field! I tried to do something but I couldnt! how can I make it work for more then 1 field? I thinking about adding the id to hide for an entire div that holds those elements I want to hidde but if there is another way to add the hide to all those elements I want to hide then it would be better

Comment: You will typically group the elements and hide them all using the parent element, such as a div. If you use jQuery, you can easily use a selector on for example class name to hide all items with for example class="hidable". But see the updated fiddle in a few minutes

Comment: yeah I figured it out by my self and then I tried it and it worked, thank you for your help and ideas.